# How to delete lines not starting with white space and integer

Tags: linux

I have a text file and I would like to delete all lines (including blank lines) that don't start with either 5,4 or 3 white space and an integer value.

So far I have manually deleted the first part of the text file and then I have identified some words on lines that I want also to delete and used grep:

```
grep -v "iter" out_modif.log > out_modif2.log
grep -v "Stabilizing" out_modif2.log > out_modif3.log
grep . out_modif3.log > out_modif4.log
```

and so on.

I have tried

```
grep -v "^[!0-9]" out.log > out2.log
```

but did not work (I guess because of the white spaces preceding the integer)

exemple of a part of the input text file:

```
Initialize using the hybrid initialization method.

Checking case topology... 
-This case has both inlets & outlets 
-Pressure information is available at the boundaries

    iter        scalar-0        scalar-1

    1       1.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
    2       8.345726e-04    0.000000e+00

  iter  continuity  x-velocity  y-velocity  z-velocity

     1  1.0000e+00  1.6601e-02  7.6482e-03  1.7253e-02
```

I expect the output of the command to be a file with only:

```
 1  1.0000e+00  1.6601e-02  7.6482e-03  1.7253e-02
```

(the other lines containing an integer have TAB instead of white space)

Comment: Would it also be sufficient to print all non-empty lines after `  iter  continuity  x-velocity  y-velocity  z-velocity`? This would be easy using `awk` instead of `grep`. Or can there be other lines to be suppressed after or between the lines with the numbers? BTW: Your command `grep . out_modif3.log > out_modif4.log` does not search for a literal `.`. Use `fgrep . out_modif3.log > out_modif4.log` or escape the `.` as `grep '\.' out_modif3.log > out_modif4.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called my file with your input `carles`:

```
grep -P '^ {3,5}[0-9]+[[:space:]]' carles
    1  1.0000e+00  1.6601e-02  7.6482e-03  1.7253e-02
```

Comment: I realize my request was not precise enough, as with your code I still got some unwanted lines:     
   468 mixed mass-flow-inlet faces, zone  5, binary.
   59764 mixed pressure-inlet faces, zone  6, binary.
   56934 triangular pressure-outlet faces, zone  8, binary.
     1  1.0000e+00  1.6601e-02  7.6482e-03  1.7253e-02  2.9422e-01

I have modified your code with following
 grep -P '^ {3,5}[0-9]{1,3}[ ]{2}' out_test.log > out_test2.log
and seems to work!

Comment: Glad I could get you started ;)